# HTML5 : Changing the value of items in localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, api, cookies, local-storage

I'm currently working my way through some example test questions on HTML5, and I came across the following:

> **How will you alter the value of the cookies and items in the Storage
>   objects of the localStorage attributes in HTML 5.0?**
>
> a.     By invoking the window.dialogArguments() API method.
>    b.     By
>   invoking the window.navigator.yieldForStorageUpdates() API method.
>   c.
>   By invoking the window.navigator.appName API method.

For a start the question seems incredibly badly worded. (Cookies and items in localStorage?? Hmmm!)

Also, I'm not convinced that any of the answers are completely correct...? As far as I'm aware `yieldForStorageUpdates()` unblocks any scripts that may not have returned so that the storage can be updated... but it doesn't actually change the value itself?

Is my ignorance showing or is this a really bad question? :-/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it seems that this was a really bad question that has since been scrapped as a mistake. No wonder, it was total nonsense!

Yeesh!

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are sometimes used as a fall back if the browser does not implement localStorage.

The [api for localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp) is quite straightforward.  None of these three seem to obviously answer the question.  [yieldForStorageUpdates](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/timers.html#dom-navigator-yieldforstorageupdates) is as you say.

For a fuller read of storage, take a look at this
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/features/storage